# Infinite integral domain and roots of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I need help in completing the argument in this problem:

> Let A be an integral domain which is infinite. Let $F,G\in A[X_i| i\in I]$, $F \neq 0$ and if $A^I $\ $ V_A(F) \subseteq V_A(G)$ , then prove that G=0. Here $V_A(F)$ = set of roots of F in A.

Attempt:  Case 1 :Let I be a finite set. Then Roots of F will be finite set implying $V_A(F)$ is finite, using  $A^I $\ $ V_A(F) \subseteq V_A(G)$  and A is infinite , I get  $V_A(G)$ is infinite. But , I am not sure which property of Integral domain to use to prove G =0.

Case 2 : Let I be an infinite set( countable ). Then, roots of $V_A(F)$ are countable if A is countable. So, i will have to make 4 cases now.

Is there a more elegant way of proving what I proved?

Comment: Doesn't the condition $A^I\setminus V_A(F)\subseteq V_A(G)$ imply that $FG$ vanishes on all of $A^I$? Therefore...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ya, I agree with you that FG vanishes on all of $A^I$. So, what result should I use now?

Comment: So you know that $FG=0$, $F\neq0$ and $A[X_i\mid i\in I]$ is an integral domain.

Answer (score 2):

Lemma: let $A$ be an infinite integral domain, and let $h \in A[X_{i}|i \in I]$. If $h$ vanishes on every element of $A^{I}$, then $h = 0$.

Proof. It suffices to show that every monomial term of $h$ has coefficient zero. By plugging in $(0)_{i \in I}$, it is clear that the constant term of $h$ is zero. Let $J = \{j_{1}, \ldots, j_{k}\}$ be a finite subset of indices of $I$, and let $n_{1}, \ldots, n_{k}$ be elements of $\mathbb{N}$; suppose, then, that we want to show that the coefficient $a_{J}$ of the monomial term $X_{j_{1}}^{n_{1}} \cdots X_{j_{k}}^{n_{k}}$ in $h$ is zero.

There is an evaluation map $A[X_{i} \mid i \in I] \to A[X_{j_{1}}]$ which sends $X_{j_{1}}$ to $X_{j_{1}}$, $X_{j_{2}}, \ldots, X_{j_{k}}$ to $1$, and $X_{i}$ to $0$ for $i \notin J$. Let $h'(X_{j_{1}})$ be the image of $h$ in $A[X_{j_{1}}]$; I claim that $h'(X_{j_{1}}) = 0$. Since the coefficient of $X_{j_{1}}^{n_{1}}$ is $a_{J}$, this will prove that $a_{J} = 0$, as desired. Indeed, every element of $A$ is a root of $h'$, since evaluating $h'$ at any element of $a \in A$ is the same as evaluating $h$ at $X_{j_{1}} = a, X_{j_{2}} = 1, \ldots, X_{j_{k}} = 1$, $X_{i} = 0$ for $i \notin J$. As $A$ is an integral domain, every nonzero polynomial may only have finitely many roots, and since $A$ is infinite, we conclude $h' = 0$. $\square$

Can you use Jyrki's very nice hint and the lemma to finish the rest?

Comment: @AlexWerteim Can you please elaborate on how you deduced that every element of A is a root of h'?

Comment: @No-One it would help to know where you are confused, since the sentence of my post beginning with "Indeed" addresses precisely this point. Perhaps it would help to see what's going in in two variables instead of possibly infinitely many: consider (e.g.) the polynomial $f(X, Y) := X^{2}+XY+Y^{2} \in \mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$. By plugging in $Y = 3$, we get the polynomial $g(X) = f(X, 3) = X^{2}+3X+9 \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$. Then for any element $a \in \mathbb{Q}$, we have $g(a) = f(a, 3)$, so for example, we have $g(2) = f(2, 3) = 19$. The point is that we can evaluate in steps: to evaluate at a pair...

Comment: ... $(a, b) \in \mathbb{Q}^{2}$, it suffices to (say) first evaluate at $Y = b$, then at $X = a$. In my post, what we're doing is first evaluating $h$ at $X_{j_{2}} = 1, \ldots, X_{j_{k}} = 1$, and $X_{i} = 0$ for all $i \notin J$. This gives us a polynomial $h'$ in one variable $X_{j_{1}}$. But plugging in any $a \in A$ to $h'$ is the same thing as evaluating $h$ at $X_{j_{1}} = a, X_{j_{2}} = 1, \ldots, X_{j_{k}} = 1$, and $X_{i} = 0$ for all $i \notin J$. By hypothesis, we know that $h$ vanishes on every element of $A^{I}$, so $h'(a)$ must be zero.